# Is it better to use solely around function instead of before+after combined?

Tags: magento2, plugin, best-practice, interceptor

The codes below can achieve the same output:

- Using solely around plugin

  ```
  public function aroundXXX(
      SomeClass $subject,
      \Closure $proceed
  ){
      beforeFunctions();
      /*Perform XXX*/
      $result = proceed();
      afterFunctions();
      return $result;
  }
  ```
- Using before+after plugin combined

  ```
  public function beforeXXX(
      SomeClass $subject
  ){
      beforeFunctions();
  }

  public function afterXXX(
      SomeClass $subject,
      $result
  ){
      afterFunctions();
      return $result;
  }
  ```

My question is: Which method is better, in terms of best practice and efficiency?

Comment: its depends on your requirements, where you want to use your plugin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends on what type of customization you need.**

**Before methods** are the first methods to run in an observer method. You can **return a modified argument**. If there are multiple arguments, the returning will be carried out according to a range of those arguments. If the returning is invalid, that means the arguments for the observed method should not be modified.

**After methods** start running right after the observed method is finished. **After methods take a responsibility of editing the results of an observed method** in the correct way and being required to have a return value.

**Around methods allows the code to run before and after the observed method,** so you can override a method. Before the arrange of the original method’s argument, a callable from around methods will be called to the next method in the chain, that means the next plugin or the observed function is also called.

> In Short
>
> If you want to modify arguments before running function then you
>   should use before method.
>
> If you want to change output of function, then you should use after
>   method.
>
> If you want to change both arguments and output of function then you should use
>   around method